# How can I access iPhone passcode in my application

Tags: objective-c

I am making an application which needs me to check if the simple passcode option for the iPhone device is set to ON/OFF and further if the passcode is set or not. Is there any way to find it out.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: You need to comment on Jacob's answer, instead of editing the question.

Comment: haha!!! Thanx for ur guidance dear. Actually I am new on stackoverflow so dont know its flow :D thanx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.thts not possible at all.

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely not, there is no way to check if the passcode has been set on a device, and/or retrieve the passcode itself.

Don't you think this might be a tad intrusive? I think so.